# Realloc resizing array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, realloc

i'm having a doubt about the use of the realloc() function in C++. I need it to basically change the size of an array by removing the first item. This is what i've done

```
cell* Queue::pull() {
    cell* data = cellArray[0];
    arrayLen--;
    cell** temp = (cell**)realloc(cellArray+1, sizeof(cell*)* (arrayLen));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    cellArray = temp;
    return data;
}
```

arrayLen is and integer and it stores the current lenght of the queue and cellArray is a cell* array which is allocated and populated previously.

```
cell** cellArray;
int arrayLen = 0;
```

My problem is: does this cause a memory leak? Does realloc free the space that was used by the first item of the array or is this basically the same as something like:

```
cell** temp = cellArray+1;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's undefined to pass to `realloc` any pointer that wasn't the return value of one of the C allocation functions. `cellArray+1` is not such a pointer.

Comment: _"the realloc() function in C++"_ Wergh... why are you using `realloc` in C++??

Comment: If you ever store a C++ object with constructors/destructors in that thing and crunch it through `realloc`, all hell is going to break loose. Don't do this.

Comment: Just use `std::vector` already and forget that `realloc`, `malloc` & `free` exist. And for dynamic allocation even forget that `new` and `delete` exist 99% of the time and just use `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`.

Answer (score 0):

If the allocated memory is expanded, the following is true:

- If the current memory segment is required after the memory space, then directly expand this memory space, `realloc ()` will return to the original pointer.
- If the free bytes behind the current memory segment are not enough, then use the first memory block to meet this requirement, copy the current data to the new location, and release the original data block, Returns a new memory block location.
- If the application fails, will return NULL, this time, the original pointer is still valid.

And you should note: If the call is successful, regardless of the current memory space behind the free space to meet the requirements, will release the original pointer, return to a pointer, although the return of the pointer and the original pointer is the same, that can not release the original pointer again